# Get reference from a String variable at defined position

Tags: java, android, file-io, absolute-path

I've a String variable named **paths** which has `AbsolutePath` to all files named as "micky"in a directory.
The value of **paths** variable is-

```
sdcard/0/albums/micky1.jpg
sdcard/0/albums/micky2.jpg
sdcard/0/albums/micky3.jpg
sdcard/0/albums/micky4.jpg
```

How can I access only micky3? I want micky3's path to be stored in a new variable say **Myvalue** i.e. **Myvalue="sdcard/0/albums/micky3.jpg"**

I tried accessing **paths** using `paths[2];` but it gives error saying its not an array value which is obvious. `Log.d(paths);`  returns everything. 
How do i access a value uniquely from a String variable? Or is there any easy approach for doing it?

Logic(What i'm trying to do)- Search for a file named "myfile" in a directory(and subdirectory). if it(directory) contains "myfile" , get it's `AbsolutePath` and store it in a variable named **myfileone**. Repeat this until all files are found and store them in variable(s) named **myfiletwo**, **myfilethree**, **myfilefour** and so on.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: one thing to note. upon accessing **paths** in `Toast` , via `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,lines[0],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` , i get `Toast` messages one-by-one i.e. sdcard/0/albums/micky1.jpg and then second `Toast` msg sdcard/0/albums/micky1.jpg and so on.. rather than all the paths in a single Toast . this indicates that String variable has stored the values separately. How do i access them separately?

Answer (score 2):

You can [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) the string by line breaks: `String[] values = paths.split("\n")`.

This way you can access the third line with `values[2]`, like you tried before.

Comment: Maybe use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` instead of `"\\n"`?

Comment: tried using this. values[1] and vales[2] ,gives Array out of bound error. only values[0] is accessible which returns all paths.

Comment: added few more details in the question,kindly have a look please.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the folder path, in this case "sdcard/0/albums", you can do:

```
ArrayList<String> picturePaths = new ArrayList<String>();

File pictureFolder = new File("sdcard/0/albums");
for(File f: pictureFolder.listFiles()){
    if(!f.isDirectory()){
        picturePaths.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

That will get the absolute paths of all files in your pictures folder.

The way you would search a directory (and subdirectories) would be to make a recursive search method.

```
public File searchForFile(File folderFile, String fileName){
    if(!folderFile.isDirectory()){ //If the folder to search isn't actually a folder
        return null;
    }
    for(File f: folderFile.listFiles()){ //Go over each file in the folder
        if(f.getName().equals(fileName) && !f.isDirectory()){ //If the name matches and it's not a folder
            return f; //Then this is the correct file and we can return it
        } else if(f.isDirectory()){ //Otherwise, if it's a folder
            File subFile = searchForFile(f, fileName); //Then search it for the filename
            if(subFile != null){ //and if it's found
                return subFile; //then return it
            }
        }
    }
    return null; //If we reach the end of the method, then we haven't found it.
}
```

You would call this with:

```
File desiredImageFile = searchForFile(new File("the folder path"), "file name");
```

If it can't find it, it will return null.

Comment: Error, array out of bound. That's really strange.I tried ArrayList<String> picturePaths = new ArrayList<String>();

                    picturePaths.add(fil.getAbsolutePath());

                    Log.d("newval", picturePaths.get(1));   




and this is the error- Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)

Comment: i added few more details in OP, kindly hv a look.

Comment: @Mukesh I added a method that should let you search a folder and its subfolders for a file with a specified filename, that should help you a lot.